# How to send a null date from AJAX call to Spring Controller

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, spring

I have a form that I'm trying to give autocomplete functionality, but the ajax function keeps throwing a 400 error when one of the Dates is null. In the form are some strings, Decimals, and Dates, where the Floats and Dates can be null or empty. The function works with empty Floats, but it will not work for Dates.

I appreciate any help.

Html:

```
<input type='date' class='Contract-startDate' required>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('keypress', 'input.Contract-endDate, input.Contract-finalValue, input.Contract-name, input.Contract-startDate', function () {
    var root = $(this).closest('fieldset');
    $(this).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: domain + "/autocomplete/autocompleteContract",
                data: {
                    endDate: ($(root).find('input.Contract-endDate').val().length > 0) ? $(root).find('input.Contract-endDate').val() : null,
                    finalValue: ($(root).find('input.Contract-finalValue').val().length > 0) ? parseInt($(root).find('input.Contract-finalValue').val(), 10) : null,
                    name: $(root).find('input.Contract-name').val(),
                    startDate: ($(root).find('input.Contract-startDate').val().length > 0) ? $(root).find('input.Contract-startDate').val() : null
                },
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item, i) {
                        return {
                            // return
                        };
                    }).slice(0, MAX_RESULTS))
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Contract autocomplete error: " + xhr.status);
                }
            });
        },
        select: function (event, ui) {
            // select
        }
    });
});
```

My Spring Controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/autocompleteContract", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=*/*")
    @ResponseBody
    public String autocompleteContract(@RequestParam(value = "endDate", required = false) Date endDate, @RequestParam(value = "finalValue", required = false) BigDecimal finalValue, RequestParam(value = "name", required = false) String name, @RequestParam(value = "startDate", required = false) Date startDate) {
        // Handle data
    }
```

Comment: perhaps something in your method is erroring out? required = false should be ok

Comment: When I commented out the dates in the ajax call, the function worked, so I have it narrowed to the dates.

Comment: you might have to look at your Spring logs then. Any errors in there?

Comment: There are no errors in the logs.

Comment: null is not type of Date that why its not working try to change `Date startDate` to string and then in your code if date is **not** empty then convert the string to type date.

Comment: Wouldn't a simple solution to simply pass an empty string instead of null and just update your server handling accordingly?

Comment: @Akhilesh, is that good coding practice?

Comment: is it working when you are sending valid dates from ajax?

Comment: Yes, it works when the date is not null.

Comment: Maybe send it a non-null value as default then. You might have to use a date formatter

Comment: I got it to work. I changed it from date to string and used adate formatter. Thank you all for helping. I appreciate it.